# Is there a way to write assertion or checker other than Verilog modeling for Zero-delay/width glitch?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm, system-verilog-assertions

I am verifying the clock itself and want to know if there is way to flag zero width glitch?

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
property check_for_glitch_fall(clk, bit disable_chk);
  realtime fall_time;
  disable iff(disable_chk)
   @(posedge clk)
     (1, fall_time = $realtime) |=>
   @(negedge clk)
     (($realtime - fall_time) != 0);  
endproperty : check_for_glitch_fall
```

Comment: This is not working for the following verilog code.
My verilog checker is working

Comment: @VishwasuDeshpande Please be specific.

Answer (score -3):

```
initial begin 
    #100 
    a=0; 
    b=0; 
    #10 
    a=1;
    b=1;
    #100
    forever 
        #10 a = ~a; 
end
initial begin
    #500
    $finish;
end

always @(a) begin 
    $display("%f edge on a %d", $realtime, a); 
    b=1; 
    b=0; 
end

always @(b) begin 
    $display("%f edge on b %d", $realtime, b); 
    a=0; 
    a=1; 
end
```

Comment: @dave_59 Can you help in this regards.

Comment: It does not have glitches, but likely has a zero-delay loop. It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: The verilog module base checker detects the changes within one time stamp. Assertion does not.